# making a PhD thesis at distance is it possible?

Tags: thesis

well i have a degree on physics but my qualifications were horrible so i can't hardly get a grant or vacancy (with paid money)

so my question is if there would be possible to make a thesis at-distance i mean i work the math at home (assuming it is all theoretical and no experiments are made) and then y send to my tutor online via PC and then i have only to go to the university to defend my thesis

Comment: Related question: [Can I get a PhD online?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11132/546)

Comment: I think that you would be better served by improving your qualifications, rather than trying to get a Ph.D. "on the cheap."

Comment: An online degree in theoretical physics is unlikely to qualify you for any job except _Professor of Cold Fusion_... ;-)

Comment: Have you done a good research project? Competition is tough, so if you don't have good grades nor good experience, the best you can do is get better grades.

Comment: no i have no experience :D i tried publishing some ideas but were all rejected :( , only have a MSC and i can change my university grades (quaflications)

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia a good research project at least? Can you try to do one? I am saying this because most professors in Sweden, for example, don't care about grades so much, but do about your projects, even if they haven't led to a publication.

Comment: had an idea about divergent series applied to the divergent integrals in QFT :) i even made a paper about this and several more ideas see http://vixra.org/abs/1305.0171 a resume :)

Comment: You can **change** your university grades (or what you call "quaflications")? How?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you aim for a MSc first, with the purpose of boosting your credentials?

If you achieve an acceptable GPA during the MSc and manage to work in an interesting topic, your chances of getting accepted in a PhD would improve dramatically.

Also, try to show pro-activity and contact professors willing to take short term research assistants, so you are able to show that the willingness to do R&D and the capability of working in a lab environment, even if you end up working in theoretical physics.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but "Why don't you aim for a MSc first" kind of assumes the OP currently has a Bachelor's degree, which is possible, but isn't stated in the question.

Comment: Certainly, the OP just said "I have a degree on physics", which could be either BSc or MSc. I think he stated in a different comment that he has a MSc.

Comment: "which could be either BSc or MSc" - or one of all the other degrees that exist around the world and that have nothing to do with BSc or MSc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to follow a doctorate online but I would expect an  doctorate to require more off-line activities than an on-line undergrad degree.

Some online universities offer on-line doctorates. Universitat Oberta de Catalunya has [three doctorate programs](http://studies.uoc.edu/en/doctoral-programmes) and they can be studied full time off-line or part time on-line, although I don't see any of them related to physics. [The Open University has PhD programs](http://www.open.ac.uk/postgraduate/research-degrees/degrees-we-offer/doctor-of-philosophy-phd), too.