# Has the pandemic changed opportunities for graduate funding for on-line PhDs?

Tags: phd, funding, online-learning, online-degree

In the past, I wanted to start a part-time PhD in History, but due to my geographic location and unwillingness to move, I realized there were no funding for a student like me. Usually if students want to study a PhD on-line, it required self-funding, which means $30k out of pocket minimum. Everyone advised me that, if I wanted to get funding for my PhD, I'd have to study it on-campus in a traditional format.

Given the pandemic has shaken up higher education somewhat, is this a situation I should revisit?

Is it now very common for students to receive a research fellowship to fund one's online PhD?

Comment: There's some strained legality these days around funding for remote students...I suspect it won't last beyond pandemic restrictions.

Comment: The situation has not really changed.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/11133/13240